# How can I download Yahoo Groups?

Tags: perl, scripting, download, screen-scraping

I want to download some Yahoo Groups (files, photos, messages, memberlist) and I've found these scripts:

- http://freshmeat.net/projects/grabyahoogroup/
- http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=62034

I've downloaded ActivePerl and the needed modules from CPAN (nothing fancy; they're very easy to find). I've managed to install them, but when I run the script I get an error after it tells me that I've successfully logged in:
"Use of uninitialized value $cells in pattern match (m//) at yahoogroups_files.pl line 244,  line 2."

I'm guessing that Yahoo changed the layout of the page or something, but I'm not able to update the script myself. I'm a newbie when it comes to Perl and understanding the way Yahoo generates the pages, I only know some basic C++. I want to mention that I'm not lazy, I'll try do fix it myself but I need your help: hints, advice, anything.

PS: I've contacted the author, but he isn't willing to update the scripts.

Answer (score 3):

You would need knowledge in the following fields:

- use of an html parser
- http knowledge ( get/post/head )
- web scraping

I suggest you focus on [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/) since it's capable of all these things ( and more )

EDIT: another solution ( that doesn't need programming ) , is this: login with your browser on yahoo groups, store the cookie, and then run wget , passing the stored cookie as a parameter. This way you'll get the task accomplished very fast.

Find your browser's cookies.txt file on your harddrive, and then call wget like this ( if I remember the commands correctly ) :

```
wget --load-cookies path_to_cookie_file -r -w 60 website
```

The full man page can be found [here](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_wget.htm)

EDIT2: Another option is to use [WebDriver](http://code.google.com/p/webdriver/) to automate firefox. You can use [this article](http://ssscripting.wordpress.com/2009/02/24/how-to-scrape-data-from-sites-you-cant-log-into/) as a guide on how to accomplish this.

Comment: I've checked wget,but it isn't that simple to use it,I've searched on google but wasn't able to find something close, wget, login based, cookies, authetication...If you tried something similar please tell me the command that you used for wget.I've tried Offline Explorer+login pass and didn't work.

Comment: Couldn't make it work, it only downloads the login page and it stops. 
I also had to use "--no-check-certificate" otherwise it doesn't connect to the server.

Answer (score 2):

By the filename I'm assuming you're using Yahoo Group archiver found here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/grabyahoogroup/

I ran the files script against the SubEthaEdit group and it works great. All of the files downloaded without incident.

Looking at the code it seems to barf while processing an html table in a while loop if $cells is empty.

Considering the code did work when I tested it it's possible there's something going on with the listing of that group's files. You'll want to try outputting $content and figure out where and why the regular expression on 243 isn't able to process that html.

EDIT: If you don't mind posting the group this is happening with I'm sure myself or someone else here can try it out and troubleshoot on their own. It's tough to pinpoint what's up when the issue can't be duplicated. Also, try the same group I did and see if it works out for you. Certainly something up with the group you're trying if that works.

Comment: I've tried various groups and I got the same results, and I'm not the only one that got this error(I've read on sourceforge that someone got the same error). I'm going to try it on another PC, maybe it's something with my "machine".

Comment: @Expansion -- just a wild guess .. are the groups you are fetching fairly low-traffic, with 0 messages in some months?

Comment: @Nate: I'm using the latest ActivePerl and I installed the needed modules: Getopt-Long and libwww-perl with PPM via this link: http://ppm4.activestate.com/MSWin32-x86/5.10/1000/ 
I forgot to mention that I run the script in command prompt like this:perl -T D:\workspace\yahoogroups_files.pl <grpnam>

Comment: otherwise i get this error: "-T" is on the #! line, it must also be used on the command line at D:\workspace\yahoogroups_files.pl line 1.
I've triedon different groups & the same:"Use of uninitialized value $cells in pattern match (m//) at D:\workspace\yahoogroups_files.pl line 244, <STDIN> line2."

Comment: Would you please explain me what did you do? I have a feeling that I'm doing something wrong.(I'm using command prompt from WinXP SP2)

Comment: Ran it off my linux box. I already had the modules installed that were needed.
Add this above the while loop on line 244 'print "$content\n";' and check the html. Modify the regular expression above if needed. You are going to have to play with code here. Great opportunity to learn something new!

Comment: I still get errors: 500 No Host option provided. And what HTML? 
I think I'll install Linux on a VM. What distribution should i choose? What compiler do you use for perl? Hope I'll manage to install the modules.

Comment: The script you're using parses the html pages of yahoo groups. The html that's being returned may not match what the script is expecting. 

I recommend Ubuntu but it doesn't matter for a task like this. /usr/bin/perl is standard on a linux system for perl and should be included by default.

Comment: I don't understand how come in my case the returend HTML doesn't match, but in your case it does. Doesn't it like WinXP, ActivePerl, or the modules I installed?

Comment: @SquareCog - Nop. They're active groups.

Comment: You should crack open the code and try to debug this. This is a forum to help with programming, not generic troubleshooting of downloaded code/your machine. Open the file, read it, try to understand it, and play till it works. If you have a specific question about the code feel free to post it.

Comment: Did it work for you? All of the scripts worked? If they did there's no debugging. I'm trying to see where's the problem coming from: My settings/software/pc or the actual code. If it's the actual code, i'll get into it.

Comment: yahoogroups_files works. I only ran that since it's the one you mentioned. You have two options: Edit the code or use another box. Debugging code will help you find out if it's a code or ActivePerl issue. Again, this is a programming forum. Reply w/o trying any code then I can't and won't help.

Comment: I've added an answer below, because here I have a limited number of characters.

Comment: Please tell me what linux do you use and what distribution of perl. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if it will help you, but here's what I did to get the message-download working:

```
http://sourceforge.net/forum/forum.php?thread_id=3283915&forum_id=209170
```

(I only used message-download, I didn't look at file-download)

Comment: The message-download is different from the rest of the scripts. As the author states:"Inspired by Ravi Ramkissoon's fetchyahoo utility."
Thank you for your interest!

Answer (score 0):

Was tinkering on this a while ago to backup my girlfriend's group messages and files from uni. Upon debugging on the latest scripts I've found out that there seems to be a bug on `group_domain` declaration (theres also a group declaration bug that i've found on `yahoo2maildir.pl` of the same project, see `$request`)

```
($group_domain) = $url =~ /\/\/(.*?groups.yahoo.com)\//;
```

in this case, i've overwritten the $request var under the function `sub download_folder()` with

```
from <br>
$request = GET "http://$group_domain/group/$group/files$sub_folder/";
<br> to <br>
$request = GET "http://**groups.yahoo.com/group/$user_group**/files$sub_folder/";
```

Answer (score 0):

grabyahoogroup works well in the latest edition, which can be found at the svn repo:

http://grabyahoogroup.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/grabyahoogroup/trunk/yahoo_group/

The version at sourceforge.net/projects/grabyahoogroup/files/ HAS BUGS AND DID NOT WORK FOR ME.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a tool that collects messages/conversations from Yahoo Groups!. I finally found this **tool that converts your Yahoo! Groups messages into MBOX format** after struggling to try to make my own and searching everywhere on the internet.

## Download tools

Both of the following are Google Chrome extensions.

- [Chrome Extension to Download Members](http://yahoogroupedia.pbworks.com/w/page/79909487/Chrome%20Application%20to%20Download%20Members) posted by Sam Hobbs (2015).
- [Chrome Application To Download Messages](http://yahoogroupedia.pbworks.com/w/page/93006447/Chrome%20Application%20To%20Download%20Messages) posted by Mark Fletcher (Jan 2016).

## Plain string to Base64 binary data

At some time past September 16, 2010 (at least for me), the messages retrieved are no longer plain text and instead Base 64 binary data (ASCII). Using this [swiss converter tool](http://www.percederberg.net/tools/text_converter.html) can allow you to read the data as it is.

#### Sample content from the MBOX format

`VGhlIHF1aWNrIGJyb3duIGZveCBqdW1wcyBvdmVyIHRoZSBsYXp5IGRvZy4=`

#### Sample result after conversion

`The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.`

Answer (score 0):

for cause, as of 2019/09

https://github.com/csaftoiu/yahoo-groups-backup

.....